# Where can I find public and known ERC20-Contracts from existing ICOs

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ico, erc-721, erc-223

In order to list real live example code for ERC20-Token and Crowdsales at a talk about Smart Contracts I'm looking for such projects?

Who can recommend me the real GOOD examples out there (and not all these broken stuff that can be find with Google and/or GitHub from <= 2017 that also is mostly outdated and can't get compiled any more with latest solidity compiler versions)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: https://coinmarketcap.com/tokens/

They are listed by market cap which might be a good indicator.

> is mostly outdated and can't get compiled any more with latest solidity compiler versions

That doesn't make sense. Contracts don't get outdated. *Bytecode* remains on the chain. Only the compiler evolves and with it the Solidity language (the most prominent of several languages, but not the exclusive language.)

These contracts are all compilable using the same version of the compiler that the code targets, probably not the latest.

Most of those contracts will have verified source code on Etherscan. After all, why should anyone get involved with a contract they can't read? You can find your way there from the "explorer" link on CMC. Those are only for convenience.

`Explorer => contract 0x9f8... => code`

Example:

https://etherscan.io/address/0x9f8f72aa9304c8b593d555f12ef6589cc3a579a2#code

There's the code/ Note, the header info says it is compiled with solc `0.4.18`. If you do that yourself, your bytecode should be a perfect bitwise match to the bytecode on the chain. Indeed, that is how Etherscan compares to give it the "verified" stamp.

Hope it helps.